# Why I can't customize templates in Django-Oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm trying to customize the base template by following the documentation. But the template doesn't respond to my changes in any way... What am I doing wrong?

**My template's path from `location()`:**

```
.../django_shop/frobshop/frobshop/templates
```

**My structure of project:**

[image]

**My settings:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            location('templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # Oscar specific

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.communication.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        }
    }
]
```

**My base.html:**

```
{% extends 'oscar/base.html' %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}
{% trans 'test title' %}
{% endblock %}
test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `base.html` is in the wrong location - it needs to be in `frobshop/templates/oscar/base.html` instead of of `frobshop/templates/base.html`.

All of Oscar's templates are namespaced with the `oscar/` prefix - so to override them you have to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my configuration, I had to add the oscar folder to templates. You saved my nerves)
My path: `frobshop/frobshop/templates/oscar/base.html`

Comment: You just need to copy the project to the folder (as they wrote in the answer above) and do not write in the template itself
{% extends 'oscar/base.html' %}